# ssh http proxy, but can't sudo in server

Tags: http, proxy, ssh

I have access to a server through ssh, but I want to be able to use that server to surf the web from my computer. I'm not sure if that's called setting up an HTTP proxy through SSH, but I can't modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` because I'm not `sudo`.

I'm pretty sure there must be a way, because I can ssh to the server and do a `wget` there to download a file, and then do an `scp` to copy it to my computer. I'm just wondering if there's a simpler way, so I can use my local browser as if it were the browser in the server (basically, I'm trying to download scientific articles in pdf format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your browser supports SOCKS proxies, then it's trivial:

```
ssh workmachine -D 7099
```

Now configure your local machine to use a SOCKS proxy on `localhost:7099`. (Any number is fine for the port.)

If your browser does *not* support SOCKS proxies, then you should run an HTTP proxy on the remote machine (like tinyproxy) and make tunnel to that:

```
# Remote machine: tinyproxy listening on 6077

# Your machine:
ssh workmachine -L 7077:localhost:6077
```

Now configure your web browser to use HTTP proxy `localhost:7077`.

This generally works easiest if you've set up your own `~/.ssh/config` to include the alias `workmachine`, as well as the public/private key pair to let you in without password entry. You can put the tunnel configuration into the config file, too (see `DynamicForward` and `LocalForward`).

Comment: I use Chrome, does it support SOCKS proxies?

Comment: Depends on the OS, I think.